# How to query MS Access using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-access, adodb

I have been using the following method to query an MS Access database using Excel VBA for over a decade.  All of a sudden yesterday it stopped working. I tried all of the following - reboot, move files to local machine, reinstall Office, a different PC, compact repair database, new database, new excel file, updating reference library (didn't see anything newer), and I've tried several other snippets of code found online.

If i relaunch excel it will work for 1-2 queries then throws the error:
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
Unspecified error

It breaks on the line:
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & AccessFile

Here is the code I am running:

```
Public Function getRS(sSql As String) As Variant
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim AccessFile As String
Dim Rw As Long, Col As Long, c As Long
Dim MyField, Location As Range
    
    'specify path to db
    AccessFile = dbPath 'public variable
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    'Create the ADODB connection object.
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
    
    'Open the connection.
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & AccessFile
    
    'Create the ADODB recordset object.
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    'Set thee cursor location.
    rs.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient on early  binding
    rs.CursorType = 1 'adOpenKeyset on early  binding
    
    'On Error Resume Next
    'Open the recordset.
    rs.Open sSql, con
    
    Set getRSOLD = rs
    
    Set Location = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: What is the content of `AccessFile` in the moment if breaks? If you query the same Access DB all the time, I think you shoudn't recreate a new connection object but keep it open (eg by using a global or static variable). Btw: As you already use early binding, you should use it consequently. Currently you have a mixture of early binding (variable declaration) and late binding (CreateObject; using 1 and 3 instead of named constants)

Comment: AccessFile = "X:\Documents\TTB Database\Distillery_V2.accdb"

Comment: I'm not sure what the 1 and 3 refer to, but it does break at con.Open... before it reaches that section.  I'll try to rework it to open the connection only once. Thanks.

Comment: You are opening a connection and a recordset but you are not closing them. Always call `Close`. See: [Open and Close Methods Example (VB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-and-close-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Olivier when I include the rs.close and con.close my recordset isn't returned by the function. It's as though closing them removes them before they can be passed to teh calling sub. I added them between Set getRSOLD = rs and Set Location = Nothing

Comment: That's because you're returning the Recordset object. So you can't close it here. You have to close that recordset in the calling code.

Comment: But then you should open the connection in the calling code, pass it to this method and you can then close the connection again in the calling code and also the recordset once you are finished with it. It's probably these open objects that make it fail after a while.

Comment: I really appreciate suggestions. I chose to open the connection in the function to reduce the number of times I'd have to write the same few lines of code. If I open the connection in the subs there isn't much left to do in this function.  Is there a property I could check to see if the connection is still open? If connection.open = false then open connection. Else get recordset....?

Comment: Might be due to something funny going on with the ADO library references?  You declare them as early bound (e.g., `ADODB.Connection`, but then set them late bound (e.g., `CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")`).

Comment: "All of a sudden yesterday it stopped working."  This may be a symptom of a new bug from Microsoft: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/access/access-doesn-t-close-properly-a-remaining-background-process-can/m-p/3103807

Comment: Have you checked the Access database for corruption (Compact & Repair)?

Comment: Turns out it was some sort of corrupt workbook. I exported all the forms and modules. Then imported them into a new workbook and it works perfectly again. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: See: [ADO State Property](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_comm_state.asp).